# Flutter Api call Unhandled Exception

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a problem with api call,
in the project i have another call and it work, this call doesn't work in any way

```
// file meteo.dart
class Meteo {
  int id;
  double temperatura;
  String name;
 
 
  Meteo(this.id, this.temperatura, this.name);
 
  Meteo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> mappa){
    this.id = mappa['id'];
    this.temperatura = mappa['main']['temp'];
    this.name = mappa['name'].toString();
  }
}
```

This is the model of the response

```
  Future ferentinoGet() async {
    var dio = Dio();
    Response response = await
    dio.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=ferentino&appid=****************');
    final resJson = response.data;
    datiFerentino = resJson
        .map<Meteo>((mappa) => Meteo.fromMap(mappa))
        .toList();
    print(response.data);
    }
```

This is the api call

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'map' with matching arguments.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:13
Tried calling: map<Meteo>(Closure: (dynamic) => Meteo)
Found: map<K2, V2>((K, V) => MapEntry<K2, V2>) => Map<K2, V2>
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _HomeScreenState.ferentinoGet (package:ferentino/main.dart:223:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _HomeScreenState.initState (package:ferentino/main.dart:43:5)
#3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
#4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
#5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
#6      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
#7      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
#8      Element.<…>
```

this is the error.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you process your JSON response as a `List` but it looks `resJson` is a `Map`. But `map` method for `Map` has different prototype.